# How to detect whether prefers-color-scheme is supported by the browser

Tags: javascript, css, themes

Is there a way to detect if the user's browser supports inheriting themes from the OS, like dark mode, using the `prefers-color-scheme` property?

I want to add a JavaScript-based theme switcher. If the user has already the support build in, I want to add a special button called "Auto". This should follow the system then.

Comment: Please explain why. If you want to default to dark mode on systems that don't advertise a preference, you can just specialize using `prefers-color-scheme: light`. There's even `prefers-color-scheme: no-preference`, but it's unclear whether that's what you want.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect the support JavaScript wise, one idea would be to set a variable in CSS, update its value in the media query for `prefers-color-scheme` and [read that CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#Values_in_JavaScript) with JavaScript.

Comment: That is a actually a smart idea! I prefer to use `CSS.supports`, because it\`s easier. It is also supported more widely than `prefers-color-scheme`, so it is clearly safe to use. https://caniuse.com/#search=supports, https://caniuse.com/#search=prefers-color-scheme. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!
`@supports` is CSS-only as far as I know. Perhaps, you need to sync the state up to your SPA or something.